# sql case self join

Tags: sql, oracle

Using oracle
The following is a simple version of my code for a self-joined table. 
There's no reason for  a self-join but I was left with the code and it returned unintended results. I've made the fix in my code but I want to understand what's going on.

I will get a 'yes' or 'no' depending on what aliases table I chose for the field *population* in the case statement.

The below returns a 'yes' but I don't want to move there if *population* = 'high'.

I don't understand? I suspect alias *b* is not being evaluated in the  case statement but why?

```
SELECT a.name, 
    a.continent, 
    a.population, 
    case 
      when b.population = 'high' then 'no'    
      else 'yes' 
    end "move there?"
FROM world a,
world b
```

Comment: changed to " case when b.population='high' then 'yes' else 'no' end ",  'then' means match, 'else' means mismatch. check this url: [SQL CASE Tutorial](https://community.modeanalytics.com/sql/tutorial/sql-case/)

Comment: you created a join but how will oracle find out what to join it with?

Comment: that's why going forward you need to explicitly declare the join.. `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN`

Comment: The comma-separated `FROM` statement is effectively deprecated because it doesn't specify the type of Join operation being performed and you have to specify the Join predicates in the outer `WHERE` clause which makes it harder to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

The query in your question doesn't specify how `world a` is supposed to be joined to `world b`, and as such **ALL RECORDS IN `a`** are being joined to **ALL RECORDS IN `b`**. This is known as a Cartesian join or a `CROSS JOIN`, and if you were to use ANSI-style joins it would be coded as:

```
SELECT a.name, 
       a.continent, 
       a.population, 
       case 
         when b.population = 'high' then 'no'    
         else 'yes' 
       end "move there?"
  FROM world a
  CROSS JOIN world b
```

This is probably not what was intended. :-)

I suspect that what was wanted was to do an INNER JOIN. Using ANSI-style joins this would be something like

```
SELECT a.name, 
       a.continent, 
       a.population, 
       case 
         when b.population = 'high' then 'no'    
         else 'yes' 
       end "move there?"
  FROM world a
  INNER JOIN world b
    ON b.name = a.name
```

or, using the 'implied' join style

```
SELECT a.name, 
       a.continent, 
       a.population, 
       case 
         when b.population = 'high' then 'no'    
         else 'yes' 
       end "move there?"
  FROM world a,
       world b
  WHERE b.name = a.name
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Explicit Join and ON

```
SELECT a.name, 
    a.continent, 
    a.population, 
    case 
      when b.population = 'high' then 'no'    
      else 'yes' 
    end "move there?"
FROM world a
  inner join world b
     on b.<col> = a.<col>
```